# Strapi Graphql deep sort

Tags: graphql, strapi

I would like to sort with strapi's graphql

I can do that by

```
{
  users (sort: "id:asc") {
    id
    username
    email
    address {
      id
      city
      state
      street
    }
  }
}
```

I can sort by the first level of columns but how do I go deeper, for example address.city, because
". / :" don't work, graphql playground returns:

```
"errors": [
    {
      "message": "select \"users\".* from \"users\" order by \"address\".\"city\" desc limit $1 - missing FROM-clause entry for table \"address\"",
```

Comment: I think we can do it for filters but it's not working for sort yet? I created a similar post, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64775024/strapi-deep-sort

Comment: @abrunet filters do not work on nested components. tested last week.