# Strapi v3 deep sort

Tags: strapi

Let's say I have `modelA` with a ForeignKey on `modelB`.

In `api/modelA/services/modelA.js`, I can define:

```js
// [...]
module.exports = {
  /**
   * Promise to fetch all records
   *
   * @return {Promise}
   */
  find (params, populate) {
    params = {
      ...params,

      _sort: 'field_from_model_a:DESC,other_field_model_a:ASC'
    }
    populate = [
      'modelB'
    ]
    return strapi.query('post').find(params, populate)
  },
// [...]
```

This allows me to sort my query and I can also **filter** deep relations when using

`curl -X GET "http://localhost:1337/modelA?modelB.field_from_model_b=example_value`

But I can't find how to sort on `modelB.some_field`.

If I write `_sort: 'modelB.field_model_b:ASC'`, I get an error saying: missing FROM-clause entry for table "modelB"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, since [Strapi release v3.4.2](https://github.com/strapi/strapi/releases/tag/v3.4.2), it appears you can deep sort your queries. Yay !

You can find an example in the tests [here](https://github.com/strapi/strapi/blob/231870717c6299f238321eabe9da3dbb940bed01/packages/strapi-plugin-content-manager/tests/api/basic-relations.test.e2e.js) of the strapi project.

Here is the syntax (as expected in my initial question):

```js
{
  // ...
  _sort: 'modelB.field_model_b:ASC'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

deep sorting is available from Strapi v3.4.2 onwards have a look
[Strapi release v3.4.2](https://forum.strapi.io/t/new-release-strapi-v3-4-2/2150)